# Запретить экспорт всех функций в CMake

Tags: gcc, cmake

Я не понимаю почему, но у меня при сборке вываливаются все функции наружу, т.е. к ним можно получить доступ...

В `CMakeLists` явно задал чтобы по умолчанию не было экспорта:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}   PROPERTIES
                                        C_STANDARD 99
                                        C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
                                        C_EXTENSIONS OFF
                                        C_FLAGS "${C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic"
                                        C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden
                                        VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
```

Но стоило мне вызвать `gendef`, так у меня глаза на лоб полезли:

```
$ gendef ./libchc.dll
 * [./libchc.dll] Found PE+ image
```

```
;
; Definition file of libchc.dll
; Automatic generated by gendef
; written by Kai Tietz 2008
;
LIBRARY "libchc.dll"
EXPORTS
libchc_url_free
libchc_url_new
libchc_url_part_fragment_free
libchc_url_part_fragment_write
libchc_url_part_free
libchc_url_part_host_free
libchc_url_part_host_write
libchc_url_part_new
libchc_url_part_path_free
libchc_url_part_path_write
libchc_url_part_port_free
libchc_url_part_port_write
libchc_url_part_query_free
libchc_url_part_query_write
libchc_url_part_scheme_free
libchc_url_part_scheme_write
libchc_url_part_user_data_free
libchc_url_part_user_data_write
```

Но самое интересное, что при вызове `ninja chc --verbose`, в терминале я вижу следующую строку сборки:

```
$ ninja clean && ninja chc --verbose
[1/1] Cleaning all built files...
Cleaning... 5 files.
[1/4] D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DHAS_CONFIG_H -Dchc_EXPORTS -I. -g -fvisibility=hidden   -std=c99 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/libsocket.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\chc.dir\lib\libsocket.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/libsocket.c.obj   -c ../lib/libsocket.c
[2/4] D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DHAS_CONFIG_H -Dchc_EXPORTS -I. -g -fvisibility=hidden   -std=c99 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/liburl.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\chc.dir\lib\liburl.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/liburl.c.obj   -c ../lib/liburl.c
[3/4] D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DHAS_CONFIG_H -Dchc_EXPORTS -I. -g -fvisibility=hidden   -std=c99 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/liburl_part.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\chc.dir\lib\liburl_part.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/liburl_part.c.obj   -c ../lib/liburl_part.c
[4/4] cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe  -g   -shared -o libchc.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libchc.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/libsocket.c.obj CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/liburl.c.obj CMakeFiles/chc.dir/lib/liburl_part.c.obj  -lws2_32  -static  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
```

Прошу обратить внимание, на присутствие флага `-fvisibility=hidden`.

Что мне нужно сделать что бы все функции не экспортировались, а только те которые будут помечены на экспорт?

Comment: в исходниках эти функции точно не объявленны как видимые/видимость явно не заданы? к mcve не пытался свести?

Comment: Нет, они точно не помечены на экспорт

Comment: похоже mingw не поддерживает `visibility=hidden` (в сорцах он прямо ругает её)... а функции придётся по-виндовому экспортировать через `__declspec(dllexport)`. символ в любом случае попадает в dll'ку (не уверен, на сколько это не правильно), а вот в соответствующую lib'ку он попадает только если объявлен с `dllexport`...